# Add one hour onto start time using jquery

Tags: jquery, time

I have two textboxes. One is for a start time and the other is an end time. How can I add one hour to the end time box automatically when a user enters a time in the start time?
The values are strings and do not have a datatype of `time`. I really cannot find anything on the internet on how to go about doing this.

**Example**
`Start time: <input type="text" id="startTime" />`
`End time: <input type="text" id="endTime" />`

If the user enters 14:00 in `startTime`, I need it to automatically populate `endTime` with 15:00.

Any ideas on how this can be done? Thanks you.

Comment: google javascript date

Comment: @popnoodles comments directing people to google their issues are frowned upon by the SO community.

Comment: Contains the startTime always a collon as seperator like 14:00?

Comment: @OneTrickPony Yes they can edit it if they wish, but just for convenience it should have a one hour default value according to the startTime. Thankyou

Comment: @Ohgodwhy asking questions that show no attempt or research is frowned upon by the SO community. So is answering such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I think this should work for you considering the above comments and your requirements](http://jsfiddle.net/vW3x4/)

```
$('#startTime').keyup(function(){
    if(/[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/.test($(this).val())){
        var startTime = $(this).val().split(':');
        var endHours = parseInt(startTime[0]) +1;
        endHours = Math.min(Math.max(endHours, 1), 24);
        $('#endTime').val(endHours +':'+ startTime[1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you for your time!