# ASP.NET MVC Using Jquery to add an hour to a string representation of time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 drop downlists, StartTime and EndTime that I populate with times in 30 minute intervals, and 
I'm trying to set the EndTime to be an hour later than StartTime when a user selects a new StartTime

My model:

```
model.Times = new[]
{
new SelectListItem{ Text="12:00 AM", Value = "12:00 AM" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="12:30 AM", Value = "12:30 AM" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="1:00 AM", Value = "1:00 AM" },
etc
}
```

My cshtml:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StartTime, Model.Times, new {  @id = "ddlStartTime"})
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EndTime, Model.Times, new {  @id = "ddlEndTime"})
```

I can set the EndTime dropdownlist to EQUAL the StartTime dropdownlist with the following:

```
$("#ddlStartTime").change(function () {                
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $('#EndTime').val(newDateObj);
});
```

But how do I set the EndTime to be an hour later?  (also handling occurances where the StartTime is 11:00 PM and 11:30 PM)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this JQuery to add hour [See Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793514/add-one-hour-onto-start-time-using-jquery)

```
$('#startTime').keyup(function(){
if(/[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/.test($(this).val())){
    var startTime = $(this).val().split(':');
    var endHours = parseInt(startTime[0]) +1;
    endHours = Math.min(Math.max(endHours, 1), 24);
    $('#endTime').val(endHours +':'+ startTime[1]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Great answer, works well except doesn't handle 11:30 PM (turns it to 12:30 PM instead of 12: 30 AM), but I can handle that with an if.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the cleanest code, but here it goes. You can use javascript `Date` to assist you with conversion of the time around 24h mark.

```
var selectedValue = "1:00 AM";
var hours, minutes, endDate, endDateString, ampm;

hours = selectedValue.split(':')[1].substring(3, 5) == "AM" ? parseInt(selectedValue.substring(0, 2)) : parseInt(selectedValue.substring(0, 2)) + 12;
minutes = parseInt(selectedValue.split(':')[1].substring(0, 2));
endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, hours + 1, minutes, 0, 0);

if (endDate.getHours() >= 12) {
    ampm = "PM";
    hours = endDate.getHours() - 12;
}
else {
    ampm = "AM";
    hours = endDate.getHours();
}
if (hours === 0) {
    endDateString = 12;
}
else {
    endDateString = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours.toString() : hours.toString();
}
endDateString += endDate.getMinutes() < 10 ? ':0' + endDate.getMinutes() + ' ' + ampm : ':' + endDate.getMinutes() + ' ' + ampm;
```

The code is a bit rough around the `.split`, but you should get general idea how to do it and make your own fine adjustments to the code.

You can find fiddle for testing purpose in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jpB9N/).